# Mutating a method-scoped variable from another method

Tags: c#

So, this is a fairly contrived example, but I can't currently think of a better way to illustrate this issue.

Imagine we have a class with a method that makes some kind of buffer and then waits until that buffer's full before performing some logic. The buffer would be written to from another thread via a public method on the class.

***(I'm only using a buffer as an example, but it's a more general question, it's pretty much the same if the thing we want to mutate is just an int; what's important is that we want to mutate it only from the outside.)***

The following implementation feels fairly clean, except for the *small impossibility* of accessing a method-scoped variable *(the buffer)* from outside that method. Otherwise, managing the variable's lifetime/cleanup is completely automatic because of said method scope.

```cs
public class FunctionScope
{   
    // this method is the only thing in the class that cares about the buffer
    private void GetInput()
    {
        // the thing we want to mutate
        // imagine it's some kind of buffer
        SomeWeirdBufferThing targetBuffer = new();
        
        // we wait for the targetBuffer to be full (or some similar logic)
        while (!targetBuffer.IsFull)
        {
            // NOP
        }
        
        // we don't really care what the buffer actually does here
        targetBuffer.DoSomethingWithTheData();
        
        // targetBuffer goes out of scope here, and
        // it doesn't exist with regards to the rest of the class
        // so, no manual cleanup needed
    }
    
    // called from another thread while GetInput() is busy waiting
    public void WriteToBuffer(string valueToWrite)
    {
        // no access because targetBuffer is scoped to GetInput()
        targetBuffer.Write(valueToWrite);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, an implementation that *actually works* is something like this, where the buffer is a class member, and we can mutate it as normal. The downside, however, is twofold: first, we need to manually do cleanup at the end of the method *(and probably at the start, for safety's sake),* and also there's no way *(that I know of)* to prevent other things in the class from mutating the buffer.

```cs
public class ClassScope
{
    //the thing we want to mutate
    private readonly SomeWeirdBufferThing targetBuffer = new();

    // again, this is the only thing in the class that cares about the buffer
    private void GetInput()
    {       
        // we can clear the buffer here so we're sure it's always empty when we want to start filling it again
        // this is very redundant, but we need it in case the buffer's
        // changed from somewhere else in the class (which we never want to happen, but can't really prevent)
        targetBuffer.Clear();
    
        // we wait for the targetBuffer to be full (or some similar logic)
        while (!targetBuffer.IsFull)
        {
            // NOP
        }
        
        // we don't really care what the buffer actually does here
        targetBuffer.DoSomethingWithTheData();
        
        // targetBuffer lives past the scope of GetInput(),
        // i.e. the only method that actually uses it
        // so, we have to clean it up manually
        targetBuffer.Clear();
    }
    
    // called from another thread while GetInput() is busy waiting
    public void WriteToBuffer(string valueToWrite)
    {
        // no access issues here
        this.targetBuffer.Write(valueToWrite);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to actually make the first version work? If not, what can be done to make access to the variable in the second version more strict?

What is a good way to approach this issue, with the main goal of protecting the code from the programmer? Language-agnostic solutions are greatly appreciated, but C#-specific ones work equally well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `targetBuffer` is a private member, and `GetInput` is the only thing that reads it, what's the problem you describe with "prevent other things in the class from mutating the buffer"? "and probably at the start, for safety's sake" this sounds like a race condition. Are you expecting the same `ClassScope` instance to be called from multiple threads? This as a whole might be an X/Y problem.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't have anything to do with race conditions, it's mostly about making sure that code even in-class can't be written *(at all, or at least not easily)* that would make changes to the buffer/variable. It's more like wanting another level of access modifiers, except this time tied to individual methods in a class. That's what I mean by protecting the code from the programmers.

Comment: Are you saying that for a class type X you want a data member that can be accessed by method A of X and not by any other methods of X? Is that correct? It sounds like you don't trust the possible maintainers of the code. C# and OO languages in general don't support access restriction by method. You could define a class that encapsulates the 'buffer' and allows for getting and setting and define a second class that takes an instance of the first class and allows only getting. Both class types could implement an interface for the 'getting' method.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [System.Collections.Immutable Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-7.0)? Conceptually you seem to want something similar, i.e. a `MyData` class and an `ImmutableMyData` class.

Comment: Of course, if you really are talking about a buffer that one thread is writing to while other threads may be reading it -- then you are not asking for method access restrictions. You need a reader/writer lock on the buffer. (And that brings us back to the observation that this may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).)

Comment: @JonathanDodds well, I don't trust the maintainers, because I'm the one maintaining it :D *(and generally not putting things up to trust if they can be enforced programatically)*. But yeah, some kind of method-based restriction. The example being specifically written around a buffer-type thing might be a mistake in hindsight, if it obfuscates the access restriction part of the question.

Comment: If method-specific restrictions aren't a thing, what about the second example? Is there some way to ensure that the variable's properly reset/disposed of aside from the good old-fashioned explicit cleanup like in the example?

Comment: @drangelikj A class that contain unmanaged resources can implement [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-7.0) and the life of an instance can be managed with a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot share data between certain methods of the same class and not others, except in the very specific case of parameters. Nor can you access the local variables of one method from another method or thread except when you pass references between the two. Since you can't pass parameters from `GetInput` to `WriteToBuffer` you *must* use some sort of data member to facilitate the interaction.

Depending on the actual requirements there are various options including (but not limited to):

- Encapsulate the read/write and buffer in a separate type.
- Use `IObservable` or similar Publisher/Subscriber (pubsub) methodology to listen to the incoming data.
- Bite the bullet and just use a data member that anyone can access and *trust other programmers to not interfere with it.*

That last option is the most common I believe. Sure, protect yourself against malicious action, but we have to trust each other some time.

---

In your particular case however there are several other issues I can think of, including one particularly glaring one: what happens when I call `GetInput()` twice from two different threads? In your 'working' code I get two instances fighting over the same buffer, and with any luck they both get the same input. Except that when there are already some items in the buffer when I call `GetInput()` the second time then those items go away. There's a chance that the two threads will process the same input, that one of the threads will clear the buffer while the second is still processing it, or a whole raft of other issues.

Then again, what happens when I don't call `GetInput()` but input arrives? The buffer fills up... then what?

Clearly none of this is good for your code.

What you need is a way to queue up your inputs and only allow one thread at a time to read them. You need some kind of queue to handle tasks that are requesting input and passing them that input as needed. While that's a little different to your average pubsub model, it's not too hard to manage.

And since I'm a fan of over-engineered solutions to things like this, let's have some fun.

We'll start with some generic pubsub classes:

```
// Very general `IObservable<T>` implementation.
class Publisher<T> : IObservable<T>, IDisposable
{
    protected readonly List<IObserver<T>> _observers = new();
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        CloseAll();
    }
    
    // Terminate all subscriptions. With prejudice.
    public void CloseAll()
    {
        IObserver<T>[] observers;
        lock (_observers)
        {
            observers = _observers.ToArray();
            _observers.Clear();
        }
        foreach (var observer in observers)
            observer.OnCompleted();
    }
    
    // Add an observer and return a disposable subscription object.
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        lock (_observers)
        {
            if (!_observers.Contains(observer))
                _observers.Add(observer);
            return new Subscription(_observers, observer);
        }
    }
    
    // Send `message` to all subscribers.
    public virtual void Publish(T message)
    {
        IObserver<T>[] observers;
        lock (_observers)
            observers = _observers.ToArray();
        foreach (var observer in observers)
        {
            try
            {
                observer.OnNext(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    observer.OnError(ex);
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Subscription class to remove an observer from the list when disposed.
    private class Subscription : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly List<IObserver<T>> _observers;
        private readonly IObserver<T> _observer;
        
        public Subscription(List<IObserver<T>> observers, IObserver<T> observer)
        {
            _observers = observers;
            _observer = observer;
        }
        
        public void Dispose()
        {
            lock (_observers)
                _observers.Remove(_observer);
            _observer.OnCompleted();
        }
    }
}

// Simplistic abstract implementation of `IObserver<T>`.
abstract class Subscriber<T> : IObserver<T>, IDisposable
{
    private IDisposable? _subscription;
    
    protected Subscriber(IObservable<T>? observable = null)
    {
        if (observable is not null)
            SubscribeTo(observable);
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        CancelSubscription();
    }
    
    public void SubscribeTo(IObservable<T> observable)
    {
        CancelSubscription();
        _subscription = observable.Subscribe(this);
    }
    
    // 
    protected void CancelSubscription()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _subscription, null)?.Dispose();
    }
    
    // Called when subscription removed.
    public virtual void OnCompleted() { }
    
    // Called when error thrown.
    public virtual void OnError(Exception ex) { }
    
    // Called when next value published.
    public abstract void OnNext(T value);
}
```

Nothing special there, just a simple broadcast publisher with a sneaky `virtual` in the `Publish()` method. That lets us add the logic for queued publishing into a sub-class. Let's change the `Publish()` method to only send items to the first listener:

```
class QueuedPublisher<T> : Publisher<T>
{
    public override void Publish(T message)
    {
        IObserver<T>? observer;
        lock (_observers)
            observer = _observers.FirstOrDefault();
        try
        {
            observer?.OnNext(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                observer?.OnError(ex);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

Next we need a listener that can feed items into your local `SomeWeirdBufferThing` instance:

```
// Reads input into the supplied buffer, ubsubscribing when buffer is full.
class WeirdBufferSubscriber : Subscriber<string>
{
    // Our buffer thing.
    private readonly SomeWeirdBufferThing _buffer;
    // Proxy property to detect when buffer has filled up.
    public bool IsFull => _buffer.IsFull;

    public WeirdBufferSubscriber(SomeWeirdBufferThing buffer, IObservable<string> observable)
        : base(observable)
    {
        _buffer = buffer;
    }
    
    // Add input to the buffer, cancelling subscription when buffer is full.
    public override void OnNext(string valueToWrite)
    {
        _buffer.Write(valueToWrite);
        if (_buffer.IsFull)
            CancelSubscription();
    }
}
```

And finally, your outer class can use the above to handle input, without ever exposing your local buffers to other methods in the class *including `WriteBuffer()`*:

```
public class FunctionScope
{
    // Publisher instance.
    private readonly Publisher<string> _publisher = new QueuedPublisher<string>();

    private void GetInput()
    {
        // The buffer to fill with input.
        SomeWeirdBufferThing targetBuffer = new();
        
        // The subsciber gets a reference to the buffer, nobody else sees it.
        using (WeirdBufferSubscriber sub = new(targetBuffer, _publisher))
        {
            // Whatever wait loop style you prefer goes here:
            while (!sub.IsFull)
                Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        
        // All other references are gone, we have data, do something with it.
        targetBuffer.DoSomethingWithTheData();
    }
    
    public void WriteToBuffer(string valueToWrite)
    {
        // Just publish the data. We don't even care if anyone is listening.
        _publisher.Publish(valueToWrite);
    }
}
```

Now your input strings get dumped if nobody is listening, and if there are multiple overlapping calls to `GetInput()` then they are completed in the order received. There's even a casual nod to thread safety using `lock` statements so that we don't trample each others' fingers.

---

#### Extending to Other Types

In your question you said this:

> I'm only using a buffer as an example, but it's a more general question, it's pretty much the same if the thing we want to mutate is just an int; what's important is that we want to mutate it only from the outside.

While it's a little tough to manage references to stack items, we can use `Func<>`s or `Action<>`s to close over local variables and achieve the same effect. We can attach that to a subscriber sub-class like this:

```
class FuncSubscriber<T> : Subscriber<T>
{
    // Called when value received, return true to accept input.
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _setValue;
    // Called after _setValue to signal value received.
    private readonly Action? _signal;

    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }

    public ActionSubscriber(Action<T> setValue, Action? signal = null)
    {
        _setValue = setValue;
        _signal = signal;
    }

    public override void OnNext(T value)
    {
        IsCompleted = _setValue(value);
        if (IsCompleted)
        {
            CancelSubscription();
            if (_signal is not null)
                _signal;
        }
    }
}

//--- Used in `GetInput()` like this:

    private void GetInput()
    {
        // Target of input.
        volatile int inputValue = 0;
        // Flag for when input has been received.
        volatile bool haveInput = false;

        // Function to parse the input into `inputValue`.
        // (Also sets `haveInput` on success)
        Func<string, bool> parseInputNumber = str => 
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(str, out var value))
                return false;
            inputValue = value;
            // Set 'haveInput' true here.
            // Could also supply 'signal' action, or just check `IsCompleted`.
            haveInput = true;
            // Tell subscriber that this was successful and we can unsubscribe.
            return true;
        };

        using (ActionSubscriber<string> sub = new(parseInputNumber))
        {
            while (!haveInput)
                Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        ProcessInput(inputValue);
    }
```

Now you have a very flexible way to deal with those messages. Just be careful not to do too much processing inside your subscribers, because it's all running on the publisher's thread.